# A problem with Solve

Tags: equation-solving

I cannot figure out why Mathematica won't solve the following equation for b

```
Solve[1/(1 + 10^-a) == b, a]
```

to simply get

```
-Log[-((b - 1)/b)/Log[10]]
```

Instead, Mathematica outputs

```
{{a -> ConditionalExpression[(2 I \[Pi] C[1])/Log[10] + Log[-(b/(-1 + b))]/Log[10], C[1] \[Element] Integers]}}
```

Comment: Because the equation has multiple solutions in the complex numbers. Try `Simplify[Solve[1/(1 + 10^-a) == b, a, Reals], b \[Element] Reals]` and you see that there remain also a few restrictions on `b` to make the equations solvable.

Comment: But even so, there is a difference between Log[-(b/(-1 + b))]/Log[10] and -Log[-((b - 1)/b)/Log[10]]. I have the result -Log[-((b - 1)/b)/Log[10]] from Maple.

Answer (score 3):

You must have made a typo when you obtained the solution by *Maple*. Anyways, the solution by *Mathematica* seems to be correct.

```
f = x \[Function] 1/(1 + 10^-x);
sol = Simplify[Solve[f[x] == y, x, Reals], 0 < y < 1];
g = y \[Function] Evaluate[x /. sol[[1]]];
h = y \[Function] -Log[-((y - 1)/y)/Log[10]];
Plot[{x, f[g[x]], f[h[x]]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {-1, 1},
 PlotLegends -> {"id", "f[Mathematica solution]", "f[other solution]"}
 ]
```

[image]